# Why does Spring Roo give persist() Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, spring-roo

I've been looking at the code generated by Spring Roo and I noticed that the `persist()` method it creates is given `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.  Wouldn't the default propagation be sufficient?

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void Entity.persist() {
    if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
    this.entityManager.persist(this);
}
```

Some additional information.  Here is the roo log that produced this code:

```
// Spring Roo 1.1.0.RELEASE [rev 793f2b0] log opened at 2011-02-04 10:01:02
project --topLevelPackage org.sotest.sscce --projectName Test --java 6
// Spring Roo 1.1.0.RELEASE [rev 793f2b0] log closed at 2011-02-04 10:01:04
// Spring Roo 1.1.0.RELEASE [rev 793f2b0] log opened at 2011-02-04 10:01:06
persistence setup --database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE --provider DATANUCLEUS
entity --class ~.entities.Entity
exit
// Spring Roo 1.1.0.RELEASE [rev 793f2b0] log closed at 2011-02-04 10:02:55
```

I am using the GAE database with the DN provider.  I simply created an entity, I did not touch any files other than issuing the above roo commands.  When I open Entity_Roo_Entity.aj I get the above code.

I will try this again on the latest version of Roo and verify the same output.  I will also post this issue on a Roo-related forum.

Update: The same code is generated with Roo 1.1.1 (latest version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SECOND ANSWER** (after additional info was added to question)

It's likely due to the use of GAE. The GAE datastore doesn't use traditional transaction semantics.  See description of GAE's transaction isolation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html). Specifically:

> Queries and gets inside a transaction
>   are guaranteed to see a single,
>   consistent snapshot of the datastore
>   as of the **beginning** of the
>   transaction. ... This consistent
>   snapshot view also extends to reads
>   after writes inside transactions.
>   Unlike with most databases, queries
>   and gets inside a datastore
>   transaction do not see the results of
>   previous writes inside that
>   transaction. Specifically, if an
>   entity is modified or deleted within a
>   transaction, a query or get returns
>   the original version of the entity as
>   of the beginning of the transaction,
>   or nothing if the entity did not exist
>   then.

There are also [restrictions on querying within a transaction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries).  With this in mind, the REQUIRES_NEW is probably added so that any subsequent reads of the entity within the "first" transaction work as expected.  Seems confusing and non-standard, but perhaps this is the best option when working in the constraints of GAE.

**FIRST ANSWER**

> There must be a misunderstanding or something else at
>   play.  I just checked with Roo v1.1.1
>   generating a simple entity with
>   Hibernate provider, and the default
>   transaction propagation is used.  This
>   is also somewhat verified in the
>   [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html):
>
> > All persistence methods are configured
> >     with Spring's Transaction support
> >     (Propagation.REQUIRED,
> >     Isolation.DEFAULT).
>
> Using Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW would
>   not make sense for the default persist
>   methods.
>
> I'm not an expert in Roo, so can't
>   even think of anything that might do
>   this. Perhaps you should post more of
>   your code, particularly any
>   non-standard configurations.  Random
>   questions/ideas:
>
> 1. Are you using Hibernate provider or ?
> 2. Any custom configuration of the persisence-unit?
> 3. Do see the Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW on all of
>      your entity persist methods?
> 4. Where are you seeing the propagation annotation. (e.g. In the
>      *_Entity.aj file?)
> 5. Is there any chance that your entity class (or one of it's parents)
>      has it's own .persist method (thus
>      overriding Roo's generated method).
>
>    [1](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html):
>      http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-persistence.html

[1](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html): ah. I think it's highly likely to be due to use of the GAE/DN provider. I'll modify my answer accordingly. In the meantime, check out the notes around GAE's transaction isolation here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html .

Comment: Added some clarification to address your questions.  Could be related to GAE/DN or it could be a Roo bug.  I simply want to know if there is a good reason for the REQUIRES_NEW as it would have an impact on some of my other, non-roo projects.

Comment: ah. I think it's highly likely to be due to use of the GAE/DN provider. I'll modify my answer accordingly. In the meantime, check out the notes around GAE's transaction isolation here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html .

Comment: It appears you are correct.  GAE certainly has a different definition of transaction than hibernate does.  This is good to know, thanks.